# How does this code access the nested array with just one index and not two?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am studying a book about JavaScript and I don’t understand a tutorial to make a quiz program, It works fine but it uses a nested array and I am having a problem understanding it.

The code in question is this one:

```js
var score = 0
var question = [
  ['How many moon does Earth Have?', 1],
  ['How many moon does Saturn Have?', 31],
  ['How many moon does Venus Have?', 0]
];

function askQuestion(question) {
  var answer = prompt(question[0], '');
  if (answer == question[1]) {
    alert('Corresct!');
    score++;
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, the correct answer is ' + question[1]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  askQuestion(question[i]);
}
```

I don’t understand how it has access to the array in function `askQuestion`. Why does it only need one index to access it?

Comment: It’s bad naming. The function argument `question` isn’t the same as the outer array `question`. `askQuestion(question[i])` passes only one nested item to `askQuestion`.

Comment: There is for loop at the bottom of the code and each array nested in `question` is passed to the function and therefore requires only one index to access it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "why it just use one index value and not two". The loop at the bottom passes what appears to be an array into the function; that array appears to contain a question [ 0 ] and an answer [ 1 ]. What might be confusing you is that the array being looped through at the bottom has the same name as the argument in the function. It probably shouldn't. The original array being looped through should be called "questions" (note the plural).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it only takes one index is because the first index is used in the function call, at `askQuestion(question[i]);`

`question[1]` for instance is the equivalent of `['How many moon does Saturn Have?' , 31]` so when it gets to the function, it is only working with a one-dimensional array, not a two-dimensional one.

It is confusing because the parameter given to the function is called `question` and so is the variable at the top, but they are actually different variables because they are in different **scopes** -- one only exists in the context of the function, and the other exists outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understan well..
Thanks to this:

```js
for (var i=0; i<question.length; i++){
 askQuestion(question[i]);
}
```

I have the access to the main array with index ì:
question[0] than question [1] and so on...
And than by the function it reads the information of nested array where [0] is always the question and [1] is always the answer.

That is correct?
And sorry but I am at begining with javascript
Thanks

Comment: I wuold like to do...but I don't find the accepted.
Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear and after reading with more attention the message of Xufox,
I cheked again the code of the tutorial and I saw my error about the name of array in the loop for, infact it is not question[] but questions[] with plural.
So that is:

```js
var score = 0
var questions =[ ['How many moon does Earth Have?' , 1],
    ['How many moon does Saturn Have?' , 31],
    ['How many moon does Venus Have?' , 0]
];

function askQuestion(question){
var answer = prompt(question[0], '');
if (answer== question[1]) {
 alert('Corresct!');
 score++;
 }else {
 alert('Sorry, the correct answer is '+question[1]);
 }
}

for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++){
 askQuestion(questions[i]);
}
```

Now I am little bit more confused.
The for loop at the bottom pass the variable to the array from 0 to the last number, so for every loop if calls the function askQuestion(questions[0]); and so on.
BUt I still dont understand in base of what the var answer knows that question[0] is the first item of the nested array?? the same doubt about the condition of the if.

Thanks for help
Frank